# Ubuntu 16.04.1 - Webcam

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo, webcam

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 (64-bit) to my new Lenovo IdeaPad 100-15IBD alongside with Windows 10 (64-bit).

The thing is that the Webcam light turns on from the time Ubuntu boots and never actually turns off. I opened "Cheese" and it was just a blank screen.

Using Windows, under device manager, I found that the built-in webcam is listed as "Lenovo EasyCamera".

Is there any chance to fix it or either turn the webcam completely off during Ubuntu usage?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the webcam off writing the following command on the terminal:

`sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo`

Type your password when asked and press Enter.